# Link in new window to be optional

Tags: javascript, html, button

Let's say I wanted my users to have the option to select whether the link they click on would open in the same browser window, or a new browser window with use of a check-box.  The check-box would override the use of targets located in the  elements.  How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery it's easy. I feel these days the "javascript" tag really just means "I haven't picked my framework yet":

```
$('#myCheckbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.myAnchors').attr('target', this.checked ? '_blank' : ''); 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BNrYs/

Without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById('myCheckbox').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('myAnchors');
    for (var i = 0, max = anchors.length; i < max; i += 1) {
        anchors[i].setAttribute('target', this.checked ? '_blank' : '');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n6EP8/

If you need legacy IE support you'd add `attachEvent` in addition to `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.be">test</a>
<input id="target" type="checkbox" onclick="changeTarget();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeTarget() {
    var checked = document.getElementById('target').checked;
    var target = checked ? '_blank' : '';

    document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('target', target);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say from a UX standpoint this is not good practice.  The HTML attribute target="_blank" is deprecated because of this.  The user already has control over this functionality within the browser.  Adding a checkbox for this could just be confusing to the user.  However, if you really want to you could do it with jQuery:

HTML

```
<ul class="links">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
        <a href="yoursite.com">Your Site</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
        <a href="someothersite.com">Your Site</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('.links input').change(function(){

    var checkbox = $(this),
        link = $(this).siblings('a');

    if( checkbox.is(':checked') ){
        link.attr('target', '_blank');
    }else{
        link.attr('target', '_self');
    }

});
```

Heres a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RX2cP/

Comment: `target="_blank"` isn't going anywhere. The only time it's ever an issue is in the W3C HTML Validator.